# Java 11: Predicate or/and on Optional

Tags: java, java-11

I'm using jdk 11 I would like to know if it's possible to write this code using `Predicate::or`, `Predicate::and` method concatenations:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(someString)
    .filter(String::isEmpty)
    .filter(String::isBlank);
```

Comment: You don't need the second predicate because `isEmpty` already implies `isBlank` :)

Comment: doesn't `isBlank` subsume `isEmpty`?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov that is not true! `isBlank` also covers the `isEmpty` case, but not vice versa. `isBlank` returns `true` for `" "` while `isEmpty` doesn't

Comment: `.filter(String::isEmpty).filter(String::isBlank)` is equivalent to `.filter(String::isEmpty)`. `isBlank` is useless here.

Comment: ehm, no ... sorry to say that, but you're wrong. `" ".isBlank()` -> `true`  while `" ".isEmpty()` -> `false`

Comment: @AKSW `isEmpty && isBlank = isEmpty && (isEmpty || hasOnlyWhitespaces) = isEmpty || isEmpty && hasOnlyWhitespaces = isEmpty`

Comment: @AKSW Yes, but you aren't taking `filter` into account. You need to consider `" ".isBlank() && " ".isEmpty()` which is the same as `" ".isEmpty()`.

Comment: Ok, I got it wrong by thinking of logical `or` relation as I thought the TO wants to filter strings that are just meaningless, i.e. empty or just containing whitespaces. I bet he wants `or` instead of `and`.

Answer (score 4):

Of course:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(someString)
    .filter(((Predicate<String>) String::isEmpty).and(String::isBlank));
```

Comment: Looks ugly :) I would use guava for this: `and(String::isEmpty, String::isBlank)`

Comment: I'd just use `isBlank` ... this also covers the `isEmpty` case. `java.lang.String.isBlank()` returns `true` if the string is **empty** or contains only white space

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just want to mention it, but indeed you showed how to use `and` here. So, it's fine